# How to use Susy with Zen theme

Tags: theming

I'm trying to change the grid system in the Zen theme to use susy but can not find any documentation on how to do it with the 7.5.5 version.

I have installed susy through compass and have added require 'susy' to my config.rb file.

But from here I'm not sure what I need to do.

Do I have to delete the _responsive.scss file that comes with Zen and code my own?

If anyone could provide a run down of the steps needed that would be very helpful.

Many thanks,

Terry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to delete the _responsive.scss file that comes with Zen and code my own?

Whether you delete specific files or not is incidental, but what you *do* need to do is replace everything in Zen's default Sass that relates to grids with your Susy-based system.

Because of the nature of Susy there's a good chance you won't need to change any of the markup Zen builds, but of course your mileage may vary depending on exactly how customised your theme is.

Comment: Thanks Clive, you've put me on track. It seems like it's only _responsive.scss that relates to zen-grids from what I can see.